# months between initial and final month

Tags: mysql

I have a mySQL table

```
species
- id                     INT
- name                   LONGTEXT
- FloweringInitialMonth  INT
- FloweringFinalMonth    INT
```

With the caveat that if `FloweringInitialMonth = 13` AND `FloweringFinalMonth = 13` it means the species flowers all year.

Is there any fast way to create and populate a new relational table kind of like this:

```
flowering_species
- species_id       INT
- month            INT
```

That would have results like this:

```
species_id | month
2237       | 6
2237       | 7
2237       | 8
20         | 4
20         | 5
20         | 6
...
```

(See also: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tc7oi.jpg)

And that way I could query for specific species flowering months or species flowering on a specific month?

I don't even know how to start to do this but I guess it must have to be a way to do it with MySQL...

Any help greatly appreciated as I'm totally clueless here.

Comment: Please share some sample data that lead to that 8, 9, 10, 1 values. Generally a month is stored as a date, so it's not clear what values you are storing in these int columns and how we can math this out.

Comment: Sure! https://imgur.com/a/PZlbBEC That species with id = 20 would have 3 records on the new table

Comment: Why does species_id 2237 have a second row with month 6 in it?

Comment: my mistake @Nick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this you need to create a table of month numbers, then `JOIN` that to the `species` table to get a list of species flowering by month. In my [demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dc9e044cd44b5f57c5d2bd66344181d7) I've created a `VIEW` called `flowering_species` which you can then query by `species_id` or `month`:

```
CREATE VIEW flowering_species AS
SELECT s.id AS species_id, s.name AS name, m.month AS month
FROM (SELECT 1 AS month UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION 
      SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION 
      SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION 
      SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12) m
JOIN species s ON m.month BETWEEN s.FloweringInitialMonth AND s.FloweringFinalMonth
               OR s.FloweringInitialMonth AND s.FloweringFinalMonth = 13
ORDER BY species_id, month
```

Sample queries:

```
SELECT * FROM flowering_species WHERE month = 6
SELECT * FROM flowering_species WHERE species_id = 20
```

Output (based on the sample data you posted plus a test species that flowers all year):

```
species_id  name                    month
1           Test species            6
20          Equisetum palustre      6
314         Holcus annuus           6
1825        Cirsium vuloare         6
2237        Agapanthus africanus    6
3126        Centaurea malacitana    6

species_id  name                    month
20          Equisetum palustre      4
20          Equisetum palustre      5
20          Equisetum palustre      6
```

Comment: That was exactly it.Far beyond my sql capabilities. Thank you so much Nick. I asked this question with just some exploration and few tries as I couldn't find anyone with a problem similar to mine... I'll accept the downvotes but Had a problem and got help. In the way I learned a bit more. Cheers.